# Oracle DB: Two identical connections running the same query from the same user, and getting different results?

Tags: database, oracle

I have a test service account for an Oracle 11 database.

I can connect to the database, by creating a new connection in SQLDeveloper, and query the data.

I run the query, say,

```
select * from dw_my_data_dbo.vw_gftr_domain2_my_data;
```

when I open these views, they appear to be defined like this:

```
-- Unable to render VIEW DDL for object dw_my_data_dbo.vw_gftr_domain2_my_data with DBMS_METADATA attempting internal generator.
CREATE VIEW dw_my_data_dbo.vw_gftr_domain2_my_data AS
SELECT 
  my_data_category,
  my_data_external_id,
  my_data_internal_id,
  my_data_desc,
  my_data_rating

FROM gftr_domain2_my_data
WHERE active_my_data = 'Y'
```

I get 1000 rows back with the data I expect - great.

My colleague does step-for-step the same thing  - same username, same credentials, same version of SQLDeveloper even: But he gets 0 rows back. No error messages or anything, just an empty results set.

This behaviour is the same for every object I have access to on the database (I only have access to views, as it turns out - the majority of which closely resemble the above, with varying numbers of columns of course)

What gives?

I'm guessing it's something do with how the database is handling multiple connections from the same 'user' - but I'm certain i've been able to do this in the past without issue.

If I'm not the DBA, is there any way to debug this issue?

## What I've tried so far:

- Changing around the queries - in functional and non-functional ways (To see if the problem was some sort of result-caching thing) - but the second session always returns no rows, no matter how I manipulate or pull the data.
- Committing (everything). No effect.
- Querying gv$session from both sessions to see if it's definitely the same server - unfortunately I don't have access to gv$session with this user.
- Disconnecting and reconnecting everything. Same result.
- Making absolutely certain I'm using the same credentials/server name from both machines.

Comment: What happens when you both select from the tables behind the view?

Comment: Maybe the table is global temperory ? can you show the us the ddl of the view with the ddl of the tables ? ( the ddl of the tables should show the tablespace name that might assure you are on the same database).. All the tables he access are empty ?!

Comment: Same thing. I see results, and my colleague sees nothing, from what we can see, this is the case for every object I have access to.

Comment: @Moudiz apologies, I didn't think the makeup of the view would be the issue - I've edited my question with a description of the view's makeup

Comment: "..I run the query, say, .." Is it really just select query? Are there no "select for update"? Ar there no DML procedures done on these rows?

Comment: @Ychdziu yes it's really just a select query - I added an example of what the view definitions look like - but even for just a select * From my_view; we see different results. haven't tried any updates as we don't need to update the data from this user

Comment: @Paul if i were you i would do the following : I am connected on the same database ? i go to the tnsname and i check the server name , alternatively if both of you are connected , get your sid and his sid and query on gv$session , can you find both ? are you on the same database and schema ?

Comment: probably it's a stupid question but ... have you committed?

Comment: @Moudiz Thanks - the server name is the same - and unfortunately I don't have access to gv$session - I'm not the dba on this server so I don't have access to everything

Comment: @FrancescoSerra I didn't create these views/tables, and I'm not updating anything....but even still I tried hitting commit on both sessions anyway - it had no effect unfortunately

Comment: @Paul can you create a test table? if yes create it and add some dummy data in it and commit ur result. then ask your friend, can he see this table and its results ? if yes .. in this table vw_gftr_domain2_my_data  try to add a test column alter table vw_gftr_domain2_my_data  add test_todrop varchar2(1) null .. is it added ?